# How to compile with Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to compile this source with Qt Creator: [QPropertyEditor](https://github.com/Oen44/QPropertyEditor)

What I do is just clone the repo, double click the .pro file:

[image]

Then I right click in the project, and build:

[image]

I'm getting this errors:

[image]

I've checked the output directory and I guess it's correct: `%{Config:DefaultProjectDirectory}`

I don't know what to do now, I only used Visual Studio, it's my first time with Qt and I can't find anywhere the option to build debug files, etc

Comment: do you have local disk D: ?

Comment: change  `DESTDIR = "D:\Main Files\Qt\OTUIEditor\lib"` in  QPropertyEditor.pro, add your path